# Return to data listing after inputting data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I got three activities, MainActivity, OtherActivity, ThirdActivity

MainActivity as Main Menu that will direct to OtherActivity by button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

then inside OtherActivity contains list of data form that need to be entered into next activity which is ThirdActivity

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {

EditText Name, Age, MPersonal, MBTI, Birthday, SNotes;
Button second button, third button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other_activity);
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    secondbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondbutton);
    thirdbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    MPersonal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    MBTI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Birthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    SNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

}
public void onClick2(View view) {
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(OtherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    OtherActivity.this.startActivity(backIntent);
}
public void onClick3(View view) {
    Intent bintent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    Bundle bbundle = new Bundle();
    bbundle.putString("name", Name.getText().toString());
    bbundle.putString("age", Age.getText().toString());
    bbundle.putString("mper", MPersonal.getText().toString());
    bbundle.putString("mbti", MBTI.getText().toString());
    bbundle.putString("birthday", Birthday.getText().toString());
    bbundle.putString("special", SNotes.getText().toString());
    bintent.putExtras(bbundle);
    startActivity(bintent);

}
}
```

and it worked well it directly send intent to ThirdActivity which is:

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_activity);
    TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    nameView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
    TextView ageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agetext);
    ageView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("age"));
    TextView mperView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mpersonalitytext);
    mperView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("mper"));
    TextView mbtiView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mbtitext);
    mbtiView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("mbti"));
    TextView birthdayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdaytext);
    birthdayView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("birthday"));
    TextView specialView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specialtext);
    specialView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("special"));
}
```

Inside ThirdActivity also contains onClick Function and redirect to main menu:

```
    public void Clicky (View vclicky) {
    Intent intentclick = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    ThirdActivity.this.startActivity(intentclick);
}
```

It worked well. But when i try to return to ThirdActivity which list inputted Data. Error Occurred when i try to click Button:

```
public void onClicky(View vclick) {
    Intent kuriki = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(kuriki);
}
```

The error message say:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.user.myapplication, PID: 3739
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.ThirdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

**The bottom-line is when I try to input data inside OtherActivity, the inputted data is saved in form of TextView in ThirdActivity. Return button will return back to the main menu which is MainActivity. Then When I try to view data by clicking Button that direct to ThirdActivity. Error Occurred**

Could you please help me why I am unable to return to Inputted Data, Also I think that I don't understand the error message. Thanks in advance

Comment: I could not understand the error or it might missing the main lines I think, so could you give me a source of the app I can run it on my AndroidStudio to try solving it ?

Comment: how do i give the source of app?

Comment: should i give xml and java files instead?

Comment: yes okay that easier for you

Comment: Sorry i dunno where should i upload the file but its on this link : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=81871677413027324864

Comment: thanks, I will try it now

Comment: I have tried it totaly it doesn't crashs on doing those actions Children Development > intering data > INPUT > Return > View data, just in caseI open the app then i view data directely it crashs is thats is what your mean ?

Comment: when i try to click on "View Data" button on MainActivity. It directly send to error

Comment: yeah it crash when i try to click View Data button from MainActivity

Comment: can you upload the changes you made? because i am really in dire situation right now

Comment: I am sorry for being late but I was searching for it very well to explain it to you

Comment: Ah Thank you very much. And i am sorry i really impatient about this because this gonna be my Final Project Assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being late, but I have searched and tried a lot to explain to you and know where is the error, the very beginning error the LogCat that you read/provide in the post those lines will not be useful for you or help you the need line to understand is this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                      at com.blogspot.dictionary.coding.android.tempdeletemenow.ThirdActivity.onCreate(ThirdActivity.java:32)
```

that describes the error and says that is in line number X (32 for me) in the code 
which is

```
nameView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
```

Firstly `getIntent().getExtras().getString("name")` means that you get the saved data (Extras) from the Intent that starts this activity which is

```
    public void onClicky(View vclick) {
    Intent kuriki = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(kuriki);
}
```

(in the case of starting the ViewData directly) which has no Extras(saved data (name,age...))
, **So** the Intent when it comes form Inputing data first then view will works while when viewing **no(null)** data will crashs

**And The Solution For This is :-**

**1. IN ThirdActivit :**

- Adding If statement that checks the intent has data(extras) or not
- Also checking that the intent it self in not = null
- Replacing the `getIntent()` with `bintent` Intent
- And Finally sharing the `bintent` Intent upon the App in order to use it in other activities by `static`

Like this

```
import static com.blogspot.dictionary.coding.android.tempdeletemenow.MainActivity.bintent;


public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_activity);

    if (bintent != null) {
        if (bintent.hasExtra("name")) {
            TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            TextView ageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agetext);
            TextView mperView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mpersonalitytext);
            TextView mbtiView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mbtitext);
            TextView birthdayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdaytext);
            TextView specialView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specialtext);

            nameView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("name"));
            ageView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("age"));
            mperView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("mper"));
            mbtiView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("mbti"));
            birthdayView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("birthday"));
            specialView.setText(bintent.getExtras().getString("special"));
        }
    }
}
```

**2. IN MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static Intent bintent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

**3. Finally, IN OtherActivity**

```
import static com.blogspot.dictionary.coding.android.tempdeletemenow.MainActivity.bintent;
```

and removing `Intent` before `bintent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);`

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. Sorry i was being impatient on this. Because i had to do my final assignment. I make sure to put your name in my reference inside my final report. Thank You

Comment: you most welcome, never mind and happy to helped you :)